# Where the TeamCity service messages should be written?

Tags: nunit, teamcity

I'm a beginner on TeamCity, so forgive my dump question.
For some reason the coverage reporting for my solution is not working. So, to run the tests I run nunit-console in a command line step and then use the xml output file in a build feature of type [XML report processing]. Test results appear on the TeamCity GUI but no coverage statistics.
It seems to be that there a way to configure the tests reporting manually https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Manually+Configuring+Reporting+Coverage but I don't know where to put these service messages:

### teamcity[dotNetCoverage ='' ='' ...]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write them to standard output. It is captured by TeamCity and service messages from it will be processed.

Pay attention, however, to the syntax. Service message should begin with `##`

Answer (score 3):

As Oleg already stated you can dump them in standard output

`Console.WriteLine(...)` from C#
`echo` from command prompt or powershell,
 ...

Here is an example http://log.ld.si/2014/10/20/build-log-in-teamcity-using-psake

There is a psake helper module, https://github.com/psake/psake-contrib/wiki/teamcity.psm1 and source is available on https://github.com/psake/psake-contrib/blob/master/teamcity.psm1 (you can freely use this from powershell as well)

It has already implemented alot of Service Messages